# hibernate criteria executing extra queries

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, criteria

If there are N employees it executes the N+1 queries. I want it to execute only 1 query.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

 @Id
 private int employeeId;

 private String employeeName;

 private Department department;

 private List<Dependents> dependents;

 //getter setter for employeeId and employeeName

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_department")
 public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
 }

 public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
 }

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 public List<Dependents> getDependents() {
    return dependents;
 }

 public void setDependents(List<Dependents> dependents) {
    this.dependents = dependents;
 }

}

@Entity
public class Department {

 @Id
 private int departmentId;

 private String departmentName;

 //Getter setters
}

@Entity
public class Dependents {

 @Id
 private int dependentsId;

 private String dependentsName;

 private Employee employee;

 //Getter setters for dependentsId and dependentsName

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_employee")
 public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
 }

 public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
 }
}
```

I am Using Criteria for Result

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.createAlias("department","department");
criteria.createAlias("dependents","dependents");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("department.departmentId",depId);
return criteria.list();
```

It Results in N+1 queries. 1st query to retrieve all employees and then for each employee one query to retrieve its details even though first query had return all the required information.

```
//First Query
select this_.id_employee as id_empl1_7_5_,
    this_.id_department as id_depart11_7_5_,
    this_.employee_name as tx_name3_7_5_,
    department1_.id_department as id_depart1_30_0_,
    department1_.department_name as tx_departm2_30_0_,
    dependent1_.id_dependent as id_depen1_6_2_,
    dependent1_.dependent_name as tx_depend2_6_2_,
    dependent1_.id_employee as id_employ3_6_2_,
from
    employee_details this_ 
inner join
    department department1_ 
        on this_.id_department=department1_.id_department 
inner join
    dependents dependent1_ 
        on this_.id_employee=dependent1_.id_employee 
where
    department1_.id_department=?
```

And for-each employee it fire one query:

```
select
    employe0_.id_employee as id_empl1_7_0_,
    employe0_.id_department as id_depa11_7_0_,
    employe0_.emloyee_name as emloye2_7_0_,
    department1_.id_department as id_depar1_30_1_,
    department1_.department_name as depar2_30_1_,
    dependent1_.id_department as nu_seque1_6_2_,
    dependent1_.department_name as is_curre2_6_2_,
    dependent1_.id_employee as id_empl2_6_2_,
from
    employee_details employe0_ 
left outer join
    department department1_ 
        on employe0_.id_department=department1_.id_department 
left outer join
    dependents dependent1_ 
        on this_.id_employee=dependent1_.id_employee 
where
    employe0_.id_employee=?
```

I have already tried FetchMode.Join, Custom ResultTransformer and even setting the eagerness. But none of them worked.

Comment: Have you found the solution, If yes kindly tell me because I am also stuck on this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("department", FetchMode.EAGER);
criteria.setFetchMode("dependents", FetchMode.EAGER);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("department.departmentId",depId));
```

Or Hql :

```
session.createQuery("from Employee emp join fetch emp.department dept join fetch emp.dependents depnd where dept.departmentId = :deptid").setParameter("deptid",depId).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being nurdy but are you sure that these two SQLs are produced exactly during `criteria.list();` call?
Because it seems that Hibernate tries to refresh each instance of *Employee*. And you are right - it is not needed when list is created. Maybe you have some iteration afterwards where refresh is called (maybe in order to attach instance to the session)?